# Is the Pundit Badge available?

Tags: bug, support

I see the Pundit badge listed as available in the [badges help section](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit) but I don't see it as an option in the "Select your next badge" section of my profile.  Also it doesn't appear that anyone has earned it so I am wondering if it is not really available to be earned.

Does anyone know the status of the Pundit badge?

Comment: It should be available, but indeed, as of current writing, [no one has achieved it](https://data.stackexchange.com/bioinformatics/query/959014/top-10-users-toward-pundit-badge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's certainly available on other sites on the network (I have it in a few), so I don't see any reason why we would be different. The "Select your next badge" simply doesn't list all available badges. The rationale for this was given by a Stack Exchange developer in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263611/203101):

> It is a problem of performance.
>
> Some of the badges are very computation/database intensive to award,
>   let alone to track in (near) real-time *per* user.
>
> Such badges are not trackable for this reason.

Comment: Great thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Bioathlete Also this is a badge that you cannot do anything to get it (although posting more comments might help), so maybe it is another reason why you can set it to track in your profile